# Backup and Restore MySQL database in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use PHP to backup and restore a MySQL database:

Backup:

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'dbpass';
$dbname = 'test';

$output = "D:/backup/test.sql";
exec("D:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump --opt -h $dbhost -u $dbuser -p $dbpass $dbname > $output");
echo "Backup complete!";
```

Restore:

```
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'dbpass';
$dbname = 'test';

$output = "D:/restore/test.sql";
exec("D:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysql --opt -h $dbhost -u $dbuser -p $dbpass $dbname < $output");
echo "Restore complete!";
```

But both are not working. When Backup is complete then I check `test.sql` file that is blank. When the restore is complete, the database is still blank.

How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to use backward slashes(not forward slashes) inside paths as you are on windows

Comment: replace `exec` with `echo`; run the generated command in your command line; read the error message.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Script to backup using Php

```
<?php
define("BACKUP_PATH", "/home/abdul/");

$server_name   = "localhost";
$username      = "root";
$password      = "root";
$database_name = "world_copy";
$date_string   = date("Ymd");

$cmd = "mysqldump --routines -h {$server_name} -u {$username} -p{$password} {$database_name} > " . BACKUP_PATH . "{$date_string}_{$database_name}.sql";

exec($cmd);
?>
```

Script to restore

```
<?php

$restore_file  = "/home/abdul/20140306_world_copy.sql";
$server_name   = "localhost";
$username      = "root";
$password      = "root";
$database_name = "test_world_copy";

$cmd = "mysql -h {$server_name} -u {$username} -p{$password} {$database_name} < $restore_file";
exec($cmd);

?>
```

Comment: when i backup then `20140306_test.sql` file is 0 byte, empty

Comment: Its working for me , pass `full path of mysqldump` instead of `mysqldump`. full path means "D:/xampp/mysql/bin/mysqldump"

Comment: i have saved the database backup in my download table and as per answer I have given full directory path of my SQL file but it still shows the `string(0) ""`

Comment: If it's multiple databases then how it works? We have tried multiple databases using the loop but it restores the first file of database every time.