# PHP Ubuntu - Backup and Restore MySQl

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22217397/backup-and-restore-mysql-in-php) and it working well in Window

But when i run in ubuntu (13.10) and using xampp

```
<?php
$server     = "localhost";
$username   = "root";
$password   = "root";
$db = "test";
$restore_file   = "/home/myname/test.sql";
$cmd = "/opt/lampp/bin/mysql -h {$server} -u {$username} -p{$password} {$db} < $restore_file";
//umask(0);
exec($cmd);
echo "Restore complete!";
?>
```

it echo restore complete but database is empty. If i run script on terminal then it working.

How to fix that thanks

Comment: try without curly brace in your `$cmd`

Comment: @Sadik it must be running because `restore complete` that show on browser

Comment: `echo $cmd;`what is the O/P?

Comment: output is `/opt/lampp/bin/mysql -h localhost -u root -proot test < /home/myname/test.sql`

Comment: can u execute that command directly in shell?

Comment: @dhidy results still not working.

Comment: @Harikrishnan Yes if i run script on terminal it working and get message `Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.`

Answer (score 0):

What is O/P?

```
<?php
        if(function_exists('exec')) {
        echo "exec function is enabled";
        }
        else {
        echo "exec is not enabled";
        }
  ?>
```

**Edit** 
Execute this command in shell.

```
chmod +x /opt/lampp/bin/mysql
```

**Edit**

```
exec($cmd, $output, $return); 

echo $output;
if (!$return) {
    echo "Success";
} else {
    echo "Failed";
}
```

Comment: output is `exec function is enabled`

Comment: maybe its a permission issue.

Comment: what are `$output` and `$return` variable?