# MySQLDump executes but not not creating file

Tags: mysql

As mentioned in [Backup and Restore MySQL database in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22217397/backup-and-restore-mysql-in-php) I'm trying to backup/restore my entire database. My code is :

```
<?php

include '/../in/db/db_config.php';

define("BACKUP_PATH", "/");

$database_name = "backup";
$date_string   = date("Ymd");

$cmd = "mysqldump --routines -h {DB_SERVER} -u {DB_USER} -p{DB_PASSWORD} {DB_DATABASE} > " . BACKUP_PATH . "{$date_string}_{$database_name}.sql";

exec($cmd);
?>
```

I have stored the database credentials in another file as follows:

```
define('DB_USER', "****"); 
define('DB_PASSWORD', "****"); 
define('DB_DATABASE', "****");
define('DB_SERVER', "****"); 
?>
```

When I runt he scripts it runs successfully with no errors of any kind but no file gets created. Also I don't have SSH access to the web server to perform any actions.

Comment: If you don't have ssh access, then how do you know the file is not being written?

Comment: Sorry. I mean my host just doesn't let me run any bash commands. I have SSH access. But I can use the exec() function in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can't pipe output by using a `>` from an `exec` command.

Comment: What do you suggest I do ? I can't run bash scripts.

Comment: Why can't you run bash scripts? What about Perl or other scripting languages?

Comment: My host doesnt let me. I have never used Pearl. I'll take a shot at it

Answer (score 0):

You can dump your all mysql database using below Bash Script:

1) Create file "dumpsqldb.sh" and write below code into it.

```
 #! /bin/bash

BACKUP_DIR="DUMPDBFILES"
MYSQL_USER="root"
MYSQL=/usr/bin/mysql
MYSQL_PASSWORD="XXXXX"
MYSQLDUMP=/usr/bin/mysqldump

#mkdir -p "$BACKUP_DIR"

databases=`$MYSQL --user=$MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD -e "SHOW DATABASES;" | grep -Ev "(Database|information_schema|performance_schema)"`

for db in $databases; do
  $MYSQLDUMP --force --opt --user=$MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_PASSWORD --databases $db | gzip > "$BACKUP_DIR/$db.gz"
done
```

2) Go to the path where you saved the sh file

3) Run below command into terminal

```
$ sh dumpsqldb.sh
```

Just replace the "MYSQL_USER" and "MYSQL_PASSWORD".

Enjoy :)

Comment: My host doesn't let me run bash scripts. Any way I can do the same using the exec function in PHP like I've shown in the question.